# MyEclipse's accelerate keyszoom in(ctrl+-) and zoom out(ctrl+=) are invalid

Tags: myeclipse

I use myeclipse (version :myeclipse-2015-stable-3.0 or myeclipse-2016-ci-7) in windows 7, and I want to zoom in/out the fonts while editing by accelerate keys ctrl+ =/-,but they don't work.

I don't want to use the way that windows--preference--color and fonts--...to change fonts size because it isn't convenient,there is no accelerate keys confilcts also,and after changing accelerate keys,they still don't work.

Any ways to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Those commands don't seem to be defined in the General->Keys preferences page, for text editing, but even though they are defined in eclipse Mars (on which MyEclipse 2016 is based), they don't work there either. I can't find an eclipse bug for that, though there probably should be one.

However, I did find a solution, if you're willing to update to MyEclipse 2017 (the CI stream or the Stable stream), since the zoom function works fine there.